# Authentication app for Django

Tags: django, authentication

What is the best authentication app for Django that:

- has configurable required fields, for example allows using email as username
- integrates with other authentication APIs, such as Facebook, Twitter, Google
- password recovery flow is configurable, sends temporary password vs. recovery link
- preferably has invitation system, so the registration process can be controlled

I don't think there is any that has all these features, so I'm looking for one that covers as much as possible. But these are features that almost any well design web service should have. So I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Have you looked at [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/)? Their [ecosystem page](http://pinaxproject.com/ecosystem/) has referral/invitation apps, the builtin accounts app has password reset links (dunno how configurable) - the only thing I see missing is the FB/google authentication.

Comment: Not yet, but I'm going to look.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There isn't one django package that will cover everything, instead there are numerous great projects that tackle each of the requirements you mention:

- **general auth** : [django-auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) - this is a part of the django distribution but needs to be eneabled
- **social authentication** : [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) - integrates social authentication with the default django-auth flow
- **registration and passwords** : [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) - adds the registration flow, including sign up and email confirmation etc.
- **invitation system** : [django-invitation](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-invitation/wiki/Home) - allows registration to be limited to invitations
- **profiles** : [django-profiles](http://code.google.com/p/django-profiles/) - allows you to extend the users account with a profile

You could also have a look at [django-userena](http://django-userena.org/) which is a new hosted solution to user management for your django app. I haven't looked into how it works or how comprehensive it is, but it looks promising.

Finally, have a look at django packages for other authentication apps:

http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/authentication/

**EDIT:**

This post is a little outdated

- **django-social-auth** has become [**python-social-auth**](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth)
- **django-allauth**: There is another good all-in-one auth app called [**django-allauth**](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth). I haven't used it extensively but I believe it takes care of auth, social-auth, registration and profiles in one app
- **Configurable User Models**: Django 1.5 introduced a [configuratble User models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#configurable-user-model) in the `auth` module so you can now edit what fields you want to make use of for your user (email only, no username etc.). This is also useful if you want to add profile-like information to your user without having to join with another table (like you would with **django-profiles** or a `OneToOne` relationship with a custom profile model)

Answer (score 2):

Here is nice and **official** comparison for only Facebook Authentication Packages

[Facebook Authentication](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/facebook-authentication/)

Answer (score 1):

Go for [django allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth). it Covers all authentication flows, Custom user model. and over 50+ social authentication providers. We are using it from a long time and it has evolved a lot over the time.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install social-auth-app-django:

```
pip install social-auth-app-django
```

Then add it into your INSTALLED_APPS (in settings) then you have to create API keys, using the steps below for the networks you want to enable:

- Google

  - Create a project on Google Cloud Platform
- Facebook

  - Log into Facebook developers and create API keys
- Twitter

  - https://apps.twitter.com/app/new

After creating project you will get the App ID and App Secret (don’t share it with any one) then add these ID & Secret in setting and provide a redirec valid url for more info